# How can I determine the next LSN on postgres 9.6.11?

Tags: postgresql, postgres-9.6

Given an arbitrary LSN and a postgres configuration file, how can I determine the number of the next Log Sequence Number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be the [`pg_current_xlog_insert_location()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-BACKUP) function.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the help. But, is it possible to calculate it by myself? Basically without running any postgres command.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question. This is an internal state of PostgreSQL. How do you want to figure it out without asking the database? It cannot be in a configuration file because it is not a constant. Reading the question again, I realise it makes no sense at all. The LSN *is* the log sequence number.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that if given the rate of growth of the file plus the current LSN one could calculate what the next position should be. But apparently, it is not possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

As of version 10+, the function to get the next LSN has been renamed from `pg_current_xlog_insert_location` to [`pg_current_wal_insert_lsn`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-BACKUP-TABLE).